# How to Extract frames from GIF image and assign it to a variable?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I want to compare a same image of GIF and PNG using python. To do that I  extracted the gif image frames using Pillow library and then I want to assign the frame to python variable to compare PNG image with gif frame by frame using `ImageChops`. So can someone please help me with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.